# Convergence of an infinite determinant

Tags: sequences-and-series, determinant, absolute-convergence

I'm stuck upon the following exercise from *A Course of Modern Analysis* by Whittaker:

> Show that the necessary and sufficient condition for the absolute convergence of the infinite determinant $$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\begin{vmatrix}1&a_1&0&0&\cdots&0\\b_1&1&a_2&0&\cdots&0\\0&b_2&1&a_3&\cdots&0\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\0&\cdots&0&b_m&&1\end{vmatrix}$$ is that the series $$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 + \cdots$$ shall converge absolutely.

The "sufficient" part is easy. Let $$f(m) = \begin{vmatrix}1&a_1&0&0&\cdots&0\\b_1&1&a_2&0&\cdots&0\\0&b_2&1&a_3&\cdots&0\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\0&\cdots&0&b_m&&1\end{vmatrix}$$
Then $f(m)$ satisfies the recurrence equation $$f(m) = f(m - 1) - c_{m}f(m - 2)$$
where $$c_k = a_kb_k$$
If the series $$|c_1| + |c_2| + |c_3| + \cdots$$ converges absolutely, then so does the product $$(1+|c_1|)(1+|c_2|)(1+|c_3|)\cdots$$
Each term in the expansion of $f(m)$ will correspond to a term in the infinite product with equal magnitude. Hence the determinant also converges.

However, the "necessary" part seems problematic. Suppose that $$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} f(m) = D$$
Consider the case $D > 0$. Choose any number $0 < r < D$. Then there exists integer $m_0$ such that
$$0 < D - r < f(m) < D + r \quad \forall m > m_0$$
Rearranging the recurrence equation, we obtain
$$c_m = \frac{f(m - 1) - f(m)}{f(m - 2)}$$
$$|c_m| = \frac{|f(m - 1) - f(m)|}{|f(m - 2)|} > \frac{1}{D + r}|f(m - 1) - f(m)| \quad \forall m > m_0 + 2$$
These equations imply that by choosing appropriate values of $c_k$, we can make $f(m)$ equal to any sequence that converges to $D$.

Now if we take
$$f(m) = \sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k}$$
Then $f(m)$ converges to $\ln 2 > 0$. Furthermore, for all $m$ we have $1/2 \leq f(m) \leq 1$. Therefore
$$|c_3| + |c_4| + |c_5| + \cdots \geq 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + \cdots$$
which obviously does not converge.

Am I making a mistake in interpreting the question?

**Update:** I found another simpler counterexample:
Let $$a_1 = b_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
$$a_k = b_k = \frac{1}{2} \quad \forall k > 1$$
Then we can verify that $f(m) = 2^{- m}$, which converges to $0$. However,
$$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 + \cdots = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots$$
which diverges.

Comment: Is it ok if you explain to me about the equality of f(m)=f(m-1)+cf(m-2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book does not define what is meant by "absolute convergence of determinants".

[This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1967548) paper seems to suggest that "absolute convergence" actually means if we replace each term in the expansion of $f(m)$ by its absolute value, the determinant will still converge.

In this case, the problem is very easy. Let $g(m)$ be the function obtained by replacing each term of $f(m)$ with its absolute value. Note that $g(m) \geq 1$ and
$$g(m) = g(m - 1) + c_mg(m - 2) \geq g(m - 1) + c_m$$
Hence $$g(m) \geq 1 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots + a_mb_m$$

Sufficient: If $$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 + \cdots$$ converges absolutely, then so does $$(1+a_1b_1)(1+a_2b_2)(1+a_3b_3)\cdots > g(m)$$

Necessary: Since $$g(m) \geq 1 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots + a_mb_m$$
If $g(m)$ converges, then so does the infinite sum $$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 + \cdots$$